# How are SQL server management studio passwords saved?

Tags: password-management, passwords, ssms

If, when connecting to a database with sql server management studio and you select "remember password"... where and how is it saved?

I presume it is somehow encrypted using your windows login password?

Comment: What version of windows, what version of SQL Studio?

Comment: Hi JNK, It's XP SP3 and SSMS 2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably uses a technology called DPAPI. There's some info about it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx. Basically encryption is based on the login password but they keys can also be backed up. In a domain environment, automatic backup is probably enabled - relying on a very secure & trusted domain controller.